# Spotify API get Related Artists

Tags: api, spotify

Is there a way to get a list of related artists through the spotify api. Like the small list that displays in the actual program?

Would be very useful if so, but I am not so sure

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's available through `libspotify`. There's a `SPArtistBrowse` class that contains a lot of metadata, including the related artists. Check out the

CocoaLibSpotify comes with a documentation package, where you can find more details on what's included: https://github.com/spotify/cocoalibspotify.

Do note that it's currently extremely slow to load an entire `SPArtistBrowse` object. I'm assuming it's got something to do with `libspotify` loading it all in one chunk and on the main thread (?). From what I know, Spotify are suppose to remedy that in an upcoming version of `libspotify`, though.

Answer (score 3):

Get an artist's related artists is now available through the Spotify Web API.

`GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/{id}/related-artists` is the format.

`https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/43ZHCT0cAZBISjO8DG9PnE/related-artists` is an example request.

For more information, see the [API documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-related-artists/).

There is also a [JSFiddle demo app](http://jsfiddle.net/JMPerez/55Y3C/).

Comment: Link-only answers are strongly discouraged here at Stack Overflow.  In this case, [it is preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include examples of how to the list of related artists using this new feature, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely! All you need is the "artist_id" and the SpotifyPublicAPI can return a list of the related artists. You don't need an access_token at all.

You can easily test the API call [here on RapidAPI.](https://rapidapi.com/package/SpotifyPublicAPI/functions/getArtistRelatedArtists?utm_source=Stack%20Overflow&utm_medium=SpotifyPublicAPI_getArtistsRelatedArtists) I've specifically linked you to the getArtistsRelatedArtists endpoint. Rapid will provide you with a code snippet you can copy and paste directly into your code to make the call.

Here is an example testing the API call using Beyonce's artist_id:

[image: getArtiistsRelatedArtists Beyonce]

Here is a sample code snippet provided by RapidAPI wth Beyonce's artist_id passed as a parameter:

[image: BeyonceCodeSnippet]